# Error when importing python module from folders

Tags: python, python-2.7, package

I have a following directory structure:

```
source
       source_1.py
       __init__.py
```

source1.py has  class Source defined

```
source1.py

class Source(object):
    pass
```

I am able to import using this

```
>>> from source.source1 import Source
>>> Source
<class 'source.source1.Source'>
```

However when trying to import using the below method it fails.

```
>>> from source import *
>>> source1.Source
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'source1' is not defined
```

Please let me know how can we use the 2nd import ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For importing from a package (unlike importing from a module) you need to specify what `*` means. To do that, in `__init__.py` add a line like this:

```
__all__ = ["source1"]
```

See the Python documentation for [Importing * From a Package](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package).